# SpiDev xfer not working when called from inside function

Tags: python, spi

I have been working on integrating an absolute encoder using SPI [(link to datasheet)](https://www.cuidevices.com/product/resource/amt20.pdf) into my project and have run into a problem with the SpiDev library for Python.  When running the test script below, everything functions as intended, printing the position of the encoder as a number between 0 and 4095.

```py
import spidev
import time

## SPI Config
BUS = 1
DEVICE = 2
## /SPI Config

## SPI COMMANDS
NO_OP = 0x00
RD_POS = 0x10
SET_ZERO = 0x70
## /SPI COMMANDS

## SPI RESPONSES
NO_DATA = 0xA5
SET_ZERO_SUCCESS = 0x80
## /SPI RESPONSES

SPI = spidev.SpiDev()
SPI.open(BUS, DEVICE)
SPI.max_speed_hz = 4096
SPI.mode = 0


def spi_trans(interface, operation):
    bytes_in = interface.xfer([operation])
    time.sleep(0.00001)

    return bytes_in[0]


try:
    while True:
        bytes_in = spi_trans(SPI, RD_POS)
        while bytes_in != RD_POS:
            bytes_in = spi_trans(SPI, NO_OP)
        msb_pos = spi_trans(SPI, NO_OP)
        lsb_pos = spi_trans(SPI, NO_OP)
        pos = (msb_pos << 8) | lsb_pos
        print(f"Position: {pos}")

finally:
    SPI.close()
```

However, when I try to integrate the same code into a get_pos() function to be called from within my Kivy update function, the response from the encoder is infinitely 0x00. My get_pos() wrapper is as follows:

```py
import spidev
import time

# SPI Config ***********************************
BUS = 1
DEVICE = 2
# /SPI Config **********************************

# SPI Commands *********************************
NO_OP = 0x00
RD_POS = 0x10
SET_ZERO = 0x70
NO_DATA = 0xA5
SET_ZERO_SUCCESS = 0x80
# /SPI Commands ********************************


amt203 = spidev.SpiDev(BUS, DEVICE)
amt203.max_speed_hz = 4096
amt203.mode = 0


def spi_trans(interface, operation):
    bytes_in = interface.xfer3([operation])
    time.sleep(0.00001)

    return bytes_in[0]


def get_pos():
    bytes_in = spi_trans(amt203, RD_POS)
    print(f"Bytes In: {hex(bytes_in)}")
    while bytes_in != RD_POS:
        print(f"Bytes In: {bytes_in}")
        bytes_in = spi_trans(amt203, NO_OP)
    msb_pos = spi_trans(amt203, NO_OP) 
    lsb_pos = spi_trans(amt203, NO_OP)
    pos = (msb_pos << 8) | lsb_pos
    print(f"Position: {pos}")
    return pos


def get_normalized_pos():
    return (4095 - get_pos()) / 4095
```

I have inspected the GPIO activity with the piscope utility, which behaves as expected when running the test script, but shows no activity on the MOSI and MISO pins when calling the get_pos() function from within my Kivy application.

I have triple checked my wiring, triple checked that the correct device tree overlays are enabled, and tried restructuring my code in every way imaginable, but I cannot determine why the code doesn't work when being called from the Kivy update function.

Finally, I am also using the [ADC Hat](https://www.waveshare.com/18983.htm) on my Raspberry Pi 4, which also uses SPI, but it uses SPI0, so I can't imagine it would interfere, and indeed, the code still does not work when the ADC is disabled.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Edit:
While I have not received any meaningful responses to my question, I did make some progress on my own. Everything works as intended when using SPI bus 0 on the RPi, so the issue must have something to do with using both buses simultaneously.

Comment: Your code "doesn't work" because it DOES NOTHING.

Comment: @Milliways Please elaborate as to how my code does nothing. Are you referring to the fact that the I don't call the get_pos() function in the code? Because I'd think it would be pretty obvious that it's intended to be called elsewhere. I'd also like to point out that you are wrong in saying my code does nothing, as it actually does work when used on spi bus 0, even though the first code works with bus 1 as I'd like it to.